# How to select exact matching rows in R

Tags: r

I have following table -

```
Id      version     .net version
12886033    1       v2.0.50727
12886033    2       v3.0
12886033    3       v3.5
12886033    4       v4.0
12887578    1       v2.0.50727
12887578    2       v3.0
12887578    3       v3.5
12887578    4       v4.0
12888639    4       v4.0
12888676    4       v4.0
```

I want to select records which has exactly one .net version installed on it by providing the version number which I want. So if I gave .net version "v4.0" it should give me 12888639 & 12888676 **but not 12886033 & 12887578** because it has all the versions installed on it. How to achieve this in R script?

Comment: CAn you show the expected output

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

# define current net
myCurrentNet <- "v4.0"

# Group by Id, filter if the group by count is 1 AND net_version matches current net
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1 & net_version == myCurrentNet)

# output
#         Id version net_version
#      (int)   (int)      (fctr)
# 1 12888639       4        v4.0
# 2 12888676       4        v4.0

# dummy data
df1 <- read.table(text = "Id      version     net_version
12886033    1       v2.0.50727
12886033    2       v3.0
12886033    3       v3.5
12886033    4       v4.0
12887578    1       v2.0.50727
12887578    2       v3.0
12887578    3       v3.5
12887578    4       v4.0
12888639    4       v4.0
12888676    4       v4.0", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[.N==1 & net_version ==myCurrentNet], Id]$V1]
#         Id version net_version
#1: 12888639       4        v4.0
#2: 12888676       4        v4.0
```

where

```
myCurrentNet <- "v4.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

will something like

```
tmp <- data.frame(Id = yourTable$Id, cnt = rep(1,nrow(yourTable)))
tmp <- aggregate(x = tmp$cnt, by=list(tmp$Id), FUN=sum)
yourTable$numberOfVersions <- rep(NA,nrow(yourTable))
yourTable$numberOfVersions <- tmp$x[match(yourTable$Id,tmp$Group.1)]

res <- yourTable$Id[which(yourTable[,".net version"] == "v4.0" & yourTable$numberOfVersions == 1]
```

work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are looking for below output:

df1 <- read.table(header=T, text="Id    version   net.version
12886033    1   v2.0.50727
12886033    2   v3.0
12886033    3   v3.5
12886033    4   v4.0
12887578    1   v2.0.50727
12887578    2   v3.0
12887578    3   v3.5
12887578    4   v4.0
12888639    4   v4.0
12888676    4   v4.0")

> y<-aggregate(df1$version, by=list(df1$Id), FUN=sum)
>
> z<-y[y$x != 10,]
>
> z$Group.1

Output:

[1] 12888639 12888676

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R answer using `ave`:

```
# count the number of versions for each ID
df$versCnt <- ave(df$version, df$Id, FUN=length)

# return the IDs that only have version 4
df[df$versCnt == 1 & df$net.version==4,"Id"])
```

or you can use the `with` function:

```
with(df, df[versCnt == 1 & net.version==4,"Id"])
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="Id    version   net.version
12886033    1   v2.0.50727
12886033    2   v3.0
12886033    3   v3.5
12886033    4   v4.0
12887578    1   v2.0.50727
12887578    2   v3.0
12887578    3   v3.5
12887578    4   v4.0
12888639    4   v4.0
12888676    4   v4.0")
```